# Prevent brute force attack on my web scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I'm working on a small multiplayer game and I have a couple of scripts tht return user info with provided auth Key. Something like

```
getUserInfo.php?auth=XXXX
```

How do I go about blocking someone's IP after 5 failed attempts? And maybe sending some kind of notification to email or just writing in a log as well.

Thank you!

Comment: What type of webserver you are using. A bit detailed info would help us too.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I'm using apache running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fail2ban` to ban users after 5 attempts. But to do that you have to write your own filter for fail2ban (which can a bit headache sometimes).

But in my opinion, writing custom scripts for authentication is not the best thing you can do. You can leverage [Apache Authentication and Authorization modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) and then add it to `fail2ban` easily. Or you can add custom `apache-filter` for fail2ban.

[Here is an example](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Implement+fail2ban+with+custom+apache+filter%2C+ipset%2C+and+a+sample+based+verification+approach) to write custom `apache-filter` to control access with `fail2ban`